# How to specify segment type in Sabre RESET API - Get Cabin For Rbd (/v1.0.0/rbd/cabin)

Tags: rest, sabre

I'm trying to consume the Sabre REST API - Get Cabin For Rbd ([/v1.0.0/rbd/cabin](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/utility/get_cabin_for_rbd/reference-documentation))

According to the page description:
The mandatory information is carrier code, RBD (or class code), origin and destination of the travel segment, flight number is mandatory unless this is an open segment type. Travel Date (departure date) is required unless this is an open segment type.

However, I can't find any field(s) in the RQ data model could be used to specify the segment type as OPEN.

EVer tried with blank, "OPEN" or null in the RQ attribute [flightNumber]. The API always response with "Flight number can not be null for normal segment"

```
{
  "segmentItems": {
    "segment": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "carrierCode": "AA",
        "bookingCode": "J",
        "origin": "DFW",
        "destination": "MIA",
        "processingDate": "2023-11-13T09:05:06.332Z",
        "flightNumber": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "lang": "EN",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

```
{
    "status": "FAILURE",
    "errorItems": {
        "error": [
            {
                "code": "INVALID_REQUEST",
                "shortDescription": "javax.validation.ConstraintViolation",
                "longDescription": "Flight number can not be null for normal segment",
                "refId": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "lang": "EN"
}
```

Does any one know how to specify "OPEN" segment type in this API?

Answer (score 0):

I got the official reply from Sabre finally. Definitely useful for those who're going to use this API:

> The way to indicate that the segment is an open segment is to change the node "segment" and change it to "opensegment" in the following way:
>
> ```
> {
>     "segmentItems": {
>         "opensegment": [
> ```
>
> Then, eliminate the "flightNumber" and "departureDate" nodes from the request.